# Is Laravel DB::transaction method asynchronous?

Tags: php, database, laravel, concurrency, transactions

I am building an application that may encounter high traffics. Here's an example scenario.

If 5 users have reached DB::transaction, will all 5 enter its function together or will 1 user enter its function 1 at a time until commit is called? Let me know if you need more details and thanks in advance.

Edit: here's more information.

```
DB::transaction(function () {
  DB::select("CALL STORE_PROC_A_SELECT_AMOUNT" ...);
  // BEGIN .. START TRANSACTION .. SELECT .. FOR UPDATE .. COMMIT .. END
  // The stored procedure will select amount and lock the row

  // Some Code

  DB::select("CALL STORE_PROC_B_UPDATE_AMOUNT" ...);
  // BEGIN .. UPDATE .. END
  // The stored procedure will update amount
});
```

My concern:

Imagine there are 2 users, User 1 and User 2. User 1 goes to stored procedure A first and locks the row when selecting the amount, User 2 waits. Once User 1 is done, it has to go through some code before going to stored procedure B to update the amount. User 2 MIGHT go to stored procedure A, lock the row and select the amount that has not been updated so that's the issue. It's a concurrency issue. I'm not sure if there are other ways to handle this kind of problem so let me know if there are thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377566/will-a-mysql-transaction-work-if-multiple-connections-are-used-for-the-queries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will a mysql transaction work if multiple connections are used for the queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377566/will-a-mysql-transaction-work-if-multiple-connections-are-used-for-the-queries)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Does that mean Laravel's DB::transaction are the same with MySQL's START TRANSACTION .. COMMIT ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you come from JavaScript/Node. In PHP every request starts a new PHP process. So while in Node functions run one by one in a single thread (usually), PHP processes run in parallel. So to answer your question, every user gets his own PHP process, a Laravel application build just for him and every function in it. Here is a [nice article](https://www.toptal.com/back-end/server-side-io-performance-node-php-java-go) about it.